# Error loading React on specific builds of IE

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11, polyfills

Some users have encountered errors loading my app on IE that seem to be webpack/polyfill issues

(Ex: SCRIPT1010 Expected identifier on a random line in chunk.js)

I can't replicate the issue and it works on the builds I have access to (11.836.18362.0 and 11.0.9600.18837), I looked for ways to test specific IE builds but only managed to find similar posts trying to do the same.

I'm already using

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
```

and my browser list is configured like so:

```
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all",
      "ie 11"
    ],
    "development": [
      "ie 11",
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
```

I also added the meta tag: 
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

The builds that reported issues were 11.1158.17763.0 and 11.1217.17763.0. Is there any way to test those specific builds to try and debug this? 
On the other side, what else can I do to make sure it will work for them?

Comment: You could ask the users to check if the site is displayed in compatibilty view. Besides, they could also open F12 dev tools to check if the document mode is 11 for IE. It's strange that the app can't run in some specific builds of IE 11. I think the issue might be with users' IE browser not your app. Please make sure [the latest version of IE 11 is installed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028118/windows-run-the-latest-version-of-internet-explorer-11).

Comment: Oh wow, thanks man. I tried fussing with all the Internet Options on IE 11 but completely overlooked the "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" checkbox, that was it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could ask the users to check if the site is displayed in **compatibilty view**. Besides, they could also open F12 dev tools to check if the document mode is 11 for IE.

It's strange that the app can't run in some specific builds of IE 11. I think the issue might be with users' IE browser not your app.